# chart control asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX and C# code

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="status" YValueMembers="Total">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
    </asp:Content>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select status , Total from ch where id = @id", con);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["id"]);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Chart1.DataSource = dt;
                Chart1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

I am using Chart Type "Column".

I want that if there is no data in database the chart are visible with his initial point(0,0). Is that possible...???

I am using sql server 2008, visual studio 2010 asp.net c#.

Comment: Don't use tags in title !!!

Comment: if i try with table that have data it works fine,but if my data table is empty it dont show the Chart with initial point(0,0).

Comment: So add that point manually to the `DataTable dt` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter how to do that please write code if you know.

Comment: @user3441151 see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a manual point in your datatable then. Here's revised code block after dataadapter fills datatable:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
sqlDa.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
   DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();
   rw["status"] = "";
   rw["Total"] = 0;
   dt.Rows.Add(rw);

}

Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Chart1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

It checks whether datatable has rows and if it doesn't - adds one with 0 value.